# List items get invisible

Tags: list

I created new list and I used XSL for the list to show it as slider. I add new item with title, image, enddate properties in the list. Items are shown as slider.

When the end date passes, I want the list item to disappear from the slider.

How can I do this?

Comment: what have you used to create a slider, is it some plugin

Comment: I hope I have edited the question correctly, can you share your XSL code in the question pls.. Maybe you want to use JSLink (if SP2013) or turn it into a Visual Web Part ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what plugin you are using for slider but if you want 'if end date passes then it should remove'.
I think one possible solution is to use some condition while processing data in XSL. Like **XSL IF ELSE**

In xslt 2.0 you can use the built in **current-date()** function

hope this helps